# OpenID -- getting user information?

Tags: php, openid

I am wondering if it is possible to request more information besides email from Google and get the name of the user also?

Am using JanRain OpenID PHP script.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.  Google only releases the user's email address.  Their server is set up to never give out any more information than that:

See their OpenID page for developers to learn more:
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html

Comment: what about yahoo? does it give any info?

Comment: No, Yahoo doesn't respond to any sreg or AX extension requests.  Although they're looking at both of these for future support.

Comment: Yahoo maybe does sreg with a few select sites: https://open.login.yahoo.com/openid/op/html/us/sreg_faq.php

Comment: It turns out that Google also has a whitelist of RPs that include plaxo.com that it is willing to respond to with more than an email address.  But Google isn't advertising this fact, and no clue how to get on that white list.

Answer (score 4):

Search for **OpenID Attribute Exchange** -- that's what you want.

- [basic overview](http://blogs.gnome.org/jamesh/2007/11/26/openid-ax/)
- [formal specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-attribute-exchange-1_0.html)

We haven't looked at it in a while (6 months?) but it was quite rough when we did. Hopefully things have improved since then.

More resources:

http://www.google.com/search?q=openid+attribute+exchange

Comment: Thanks. The more I read, the more I realise how screwed up OpenID is. I wish all these big organizations could just follow one simple standard.

Comment: Um, they do?  OpenID is being pretty well adhered to by the big organizations.  The extensions to OpenID are a bit splintered right now though.

Answer (score 1):

I normally read the manual only when truly defeated. For 3 days, I have tried different ways to fetch user attributes from those two giant OpenID providers, but only managed to fetch the "email" attribute from Google and absolutely nothing from Yahoo. And then I had to read the dreaded manual, even those vague OpenID specifications.

So why implement a standard and not fully support it? Why pretend that there is any viability to OpenID if the big parties will not cooperate with the smaller parties when it comes to information exchange.

I guess the basic sign up and sign in process wins after all... Who really needs to know about XRIs and URLs anyway?

Comment: Now it seems I can fetch the first name, last name, and country from Google.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to rely on any user information anyway. See if it's part of the OP's reply, and if it isn't, provide the user with a form where he can complete the required fields.